# Specification of 'Definitely'

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

A person asks:"Did Jim eat the apples,right?"

Answer 1: "He ate those apples"

Answer2: " He DEFINITELY ate those apples"

Do these answers have a difference? What is it?

Comment: "Definitely" adds the meaning of "without any doubt". If you decide not to use "definitely", you simply state the fact that he ate the apples.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that adding the "definitely" implies that you are asserting that there should be no doubt that Jim ate those apples.

Answer (score 2):

> A person asks:"Did Jim eat the apples, right?"

They shouldn't add "right?" onto the end of what is already a question.  They'd only put it after a statement of fact, and then the "right?" is a way of asking for confirmation of the statement that's been made.  Such as:

```
"Jim ate the apples, right?"
```

> Answer 1: "He ate those apples."
>
> Answer 2: "He DEFINITELY ate those apples."

If the sentence was just *"He definitely ate those apples"*, it would simply suggest the person answering is more certain.

But if you are reading it all caps as DEFINITELY (or if it was spoken and said in a *very* exaggerated way), then that draws attention to the word in a way that should suggest "something more is going on".

What could that be?

- It is very serious for some reason.  Jim has been caught red handed, and likely needs to be punished.
- Eating the apples might not be a big deal at all, so asking about it might be seen as silly.  Emphasizing DEFINITELY--as if it were a severe crime to have eaten the apples--could be making fun of the questioner.
- The person answering may have eaten the apples, and not Jim.  This might even be known to the person asking the question.  By saying Jim DEFINITELY ate the apples--even though he did not--it shows being "in on the joke".

My point is: when you see strong emphasis--and the subject matter appears silly--the emphasis may all be part of the silliness.